# grep to find files that contain a string greater than x characters long?

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expressions

Is it possible to locate files in a directory that have strings (with no spaces) longer than x length?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I consider myself a regex noob, but I created a bunch of files with variable length strings in them and I think I got what you wanted, try this:

`user@host$ grep -e '[^\ ]\{7,\}' *`

---

For those who don't quite understand this:

`-e` makes grep search using a regex.  `[^\ ]` means to match a single character except space.  `\{7,\}` means to match a string of 7 or more characters.  If you were to put another number afther , it would be strings between 7 and x characters.

Comment: To use any 'space' as a break (space, tab etc), use a similar Perl regex: `grep -P '[\S]{7,}' *`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the example above to work. I was searching for lines in a CSV file longer than 10000 characters. I messed around quite a bit and got this...
Find lines longer than 9999 characters...

```
grep -a -e '[^\ ]\{9999,\}' *.csv >../my-file.csv
```

And this is what I really needed. Lines in CSV file less than 10000 characters.
find lines less than 9999 characters

```
grep -a -v -e '[^\ ]\{9999,\}' *.csv >../my-file.csv
```

Comment: Hopefully it completed in less than 12 parsecs?